# Prevent content from changing to multiple lines when contents overflows in IE

Tags: css, cross-browser

This is a cross-browser style compatibility problem. And the effect is unexpected in Internet Explorer(<=7.0)

The sample webpage is [here](http://www.pinglun.la/demo.html#pll-comment-here)

Notice the `.pll_viewpoint`  element(The boxes whose colors changes gradually from red to grey).

The **expected** effect should be:(See it in Chrome, FF, Opera or IE >= 8.0)

New box should switch to new row if the width of upper row cannot contain this new box without overflowing the container's width.

However the effect in IE 7.0  is:(See it in IE <= 7.0)

The "extra" box of the upper row remains to be placed in the upper row, however, with its "extra" content being squeezed and the containing box being taller.

Any hint? Thanks.

Comment: I was only able to add one 'new' tag to the list but no more, which means I can't get close to overflowing the row as you described above. Please add extra tags to ensure the desired 'bug' is visible.